# How to create json data from multidimension array (each month in year)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, foreach

I need to export a set of json data for highchart. But I'm having a problem with looping.
I've got 2 set of arrays:

1. Years Array (2015,2014,2013,2012) - form MySQL
2. Month Array (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12)

So I make it in array - multidimensional. With this code.

```
$sql_arrYr=mysqli_query($con,"select year(bk_date1) as arrYr from booking_db group by year(bk_date1) order by arrYr asc");
while($rec_arrYr=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_arrYr)){
    $arrYr[$rec_arrYr['arrYr']]=array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
}
```

Then I've got:

```
Array ( [2015] => Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 02 [2] => 03 [3] => 04 [4] => 05 [5] => 06 [6] => 07 [7] => 08 [8] => 09 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 )...);
```

Which is looking good coz I have all data I need in a set of arrays - year and each month values.

So I continue with fetching data from mySQL with this code.

```
foreach($arrYr as $key=>$val){
    $rows=array();
    $rows[type]='spline';
    $rows[name]=$key;

    foreach($val as $mon){
        $sql_nBk=mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) as nBkr from booking_db where year(bk_date1)='$key' and month(bk_date1)='$mon'");
        $rec_nBk=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_nBk);
            $rows[data][]=$rec_nBk['nBkr']; 
    }
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

The problem happened here. It's not loop. The only line I've got is.

```
{"type":"spline","name":2015,"data":["9","8","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}
```

Which I expect this:

```
{"type":"spline","name":2015,"data":["9","8","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}
{"type":"spline","name":2014,"data":["9","8","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}
{"type":"spline","name":2013,"data":["9","8","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}
{"type":"spline","name":2012,"data":["9","8","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}
```

Please give me a reason why it's not loop. Even I put them in a right loop.

Comment: You are resetting `$rows` to an empty array each iteration of your loop...

Comment: I don't understand. Please be specific.

Comment: Try to follow your own code logically, especially the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please give me a clue. Should I use `foreach` in the 2nd loop or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `$rows` to an empty array each time through the outer loop.  Also, you can't have duplicate keys.  The first `type` is overwritten by the next (also `name` and `data`) so you have to make it multidimensional.  You can use the `$key` variable for this to make it easy, or implement a counter `$i` and use `$i++` or something.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arrYr as $key=>$val){
    $rows[$i]['type']='spline';
    $rows[$i]['name']=$key;

    foreach($val as $mon){
        $sql_nBk=mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) as nBkr from booking_db where year(bk_date1)='$key' and month(bk_date1)='$mon'");
        $rec_nBk=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_nBk);
            $rows[$i]['data'][]=$rec_nBk['nBkr']; 
    }
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: AbraCadaver. the code produced a wrong format : `"2015":{"type":"spline","name":2015,"data":["9","8","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}}`

Comment: Edited.  Try a 0 based counter.

Comment: Perfect! AbraCadaver. The format is correct and the code is brilliant now. Thank you very much.